# Screen Flow Time Component

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

Is there a time only input component for screen flows? I could only find a Date and Date & Time components. Is there a way to add to a Flow screen an input field with only time selection?

[image]

Comment: use the [UnofficialSf.com Time picker](https://unofficialsf.com/building-a-declarative-time-picker-and-working-with-time-in-flows-and-how-summer-21-helps/)

Answer (score 1):

The Time field type is [not supported](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_field_time_overview.htm&type=5) in Flow Builder which is why no component for it exists.

> Be aware of these limitations when using a time field type. The time field:
>
> - **Isn’t supported in Flow Builder**, Process Builder, and Schema Builder
> - Doesn't support the creation of custom index for SOQL queries
> - Isn’t available for standard lookup relationships in external objects

You'll have to create your own component for this (LWC) to make it look as in your screenshot. There could be a more declarative option, depending on your need, as shown in [unofficialsf](https://unofficialsf.com/building-a-declarative-time-picker-and-working-with-time-in-flows-and-how-summer-21-helps/) on leveraging columns/sections and multiple picklists inputs (assuming you're selecting specific time increments: 0 minute, 15 minutes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Time only input for the screen elements, these are the only ones available at the moment unfortunately:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_screencmp.htm&type=5

You'll need to use a text input, or could consider using HH and MM option lists if you're looking for time data in HH:MM format